# Does `git push` work as shorthand for `git push origin newfeature`?

Tags: git, git-push

I note that the default behaviour of `git push origin` is to "push all branches with same local and distant name".

If I create a new branch `newfeature` and check it out, will `git push` push the branch to `origin` by default?

Or do I need to use `git push origin newfeature` even when it's checked out?

Further, how does the command `git push HEAD` relate to this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, it will push `newfeature` if and only if a branch called `newfeature` already exists on the remote.

You can change this by using the `push.default` config variable.

`git push HEAD` is essentially a shorthand for `git push <name of checked out branch>` if you have a branch checked out.

Comment: Does this mean that `git push HEAD` and `git push` have exactly the same functionality, namely pushing the checked out branch to the remote (as long as a branch with the same name already exists on remote)?

Comment: No. `git push`, by default, pushes *all* local branches that have matching branches on the remote. So if you have a local `A`, a local `B`, and a local `C`, and there are `A` and `C` on the remote, both `A` and `C` will be pushed (but not `B`, since there's no matching remote `B` already).